# c++ auto cin example

Tags: c++, cin, auto

I am getting error like

```
/hackerearth/CPP14_28/s_e3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: /hackerearth/CPP14_28/s_e3.cpp:6:10: error: declaration of ‘auto x’ has no initializer auto x; ^
```

My code is ,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

I want similar functionality that data type should be dynamically assigned

Comment: You can't do that. Types are determined at compile time in C++.

Comment: I hope it is possible in c++14 https://preshing.com/20141202/cpp-has-become-more-pythonic/  . But i count not find the way t do it

Comment: You can not use 'auto x;' you need to use according to reference [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto]

Comment: how to do it ??

Comment: `auto` doesn't work that way. You could maybe take input as a string and then make some tests to determine what you can convert it to.

Comment: `auto` determines the type of the variable based on what you initialize it with. No initialization, no type. `auto x = 0;`, x is an `int`. `auto x = 0.0;`, `x` is a `double`. `auto x = Chainsaw()`, `x` is a `Chainsaw`.

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing the `auto` keyword. **The type that actually gets used is determined by the value used to initialize the variable at compile time.** It has nothing to do with the ability to determine the type of variable to use at runtime.

For example, if you write `auto x = 0`, the compiler sees that you're initializing the variable with an int and pretty much compiles it as if it was `int x = 0`.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to take the input as a string and parse it later, or somehow determine what type of input it is before reading the value.

Answer (score 0):

Objects declared with auto typing need to copy their static type from their initializers; What your 'x' is missing.
C++ - just like C - is a statically typed language. Extra string processing is needed to decode the input string value. If the set of possible types is limited to a known countable set, a proper std::variant could be used to hold the value.

Comment: "Unfortunately, C++ - just like C - is a statically typed language" - I disagree strongly with that. In my opinion it is a *Very good* thing that C++ is statically typed. Dynamically typed languages may *seem* convenient, but all too often open the door to tricky type related errors at runtime.

Comment: No disagreements. Just sympathy with the OP.

Comment: IMHO answers need to be purely factual. Sympathy and the like has no place there. Just facts.

Comment: That word, I just removed.